# Polymer 2.0 How to createElement then import with Polymer.importHref and pass data with setAttribute

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I am creating an element, importing it and setting attribute with data. I want the code to execute only if the element hasn't been imported and created before.
When the function is called I get the following error:

```
this._dialogPopUp.open is not a function
```

What is happening is that `this._dialogPopUp.open();` is executing before the element is created and imported. If I hit the button for the second time the pop-up works because it has been created and imported before. How can I make it wait for the element to be created and imported and then continue the execution?

Currently I have this implementation:

```
_loadDialogPopUp(e) {
  let me = this;
  if(!me._dialogPopUp){
    me._dialogPopUp = document.createElement('su-dialog');
    Polymer.importHref(this.resolveUrl('su-dialog.html'), (e) => {
      this.root.appendChild(this._dialogPopUp);
    });
  }
  customElements.whenDefined('su-dialog').then(() => {
    me._dialogPopUp.open();
    me._dialogPopUp.setAttribute('uid', this.user.uid);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to check if the element is actually "upgraded" before you can use it's functions. Luckily the standard thought of that.

```
customElements.whenDefined('su-dialog').then(() => {
  this._dialogPopUp.open();
  this._dialogPopUp.setAttribute('uid', this.user.uid);
});
```

for more Details see
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/building-components/customelements

Comment: Thank you, seems the right direction. I have updated the code implementing `customElements.whenDefined` . How can I get a reference of the newly created element?